# Is it a good practice to write multiple concise statements in one line?

Tags: c, coding-style

I am prone to writing code like this:

```
if (*t) while (*++t);
```

It reads: if string t does not start with /0, then move to the end.

Note the while loop has no body, so the semicolon terminates it.

I'd like to know if it is good practice to do this? Why and why not?

C is one of the oldest popular language in use today. I believe there's a good chance of finding one or more established style guide(s).

I know that Google has one for their C++ open source projects - http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml

Can anyone point me to resources on why or why not write code in certain manner?

Comment: I usually prefer only one statement per line. But if my "Enter" key is broken.. That's another story.

Comment: `/0` ?? `white loop` ??

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan do you mean my statement and yours are equal? They are not. If I have a string "\0" - your statement will have t end up 1 place after the end of the string. while mine will remain at position 0. (See you have edited your original comment that the statement equals: while (*++t);)

Comment: @kev Yes Kev, I have delete that comment as that was wrong.

Comment: It is good practice to write code that is readable.

Comment: what was wrong with `while (*t) ++t;` ?

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is a good practice to write separate lines of code. Like in case of large pieces of code, debugging is clearer if we write code in separate lines.

Comment: +1 for mentioning debugging.  Just try placing a breakpoint between two statements on the same physical line.

Answer (score 1):

It depends! Who is going to have to read and maintain this code? Coding standards exist for two major reasons:

1. To make code more readable and maintainable. When there are multiple developers, it makes code more consisent (which is more readable).
2. To discourage common errors. For example, a standard might require putting literals first in conditionals to discourage the assignment-as-comparison bug.

How do these goals apply to your specific code? Are you prone to making mistakes? If this is Linux kernel code, it's a lot more tolerable to have code like this than if it's a web app maintained by entry level programmers.

> It reads: if string t does not start with /0, then move to the end.

Then consider putting a comment on it that says that.

Comment: I agree. Often it happens that you come up with a formula or just as in this case, a very generic-looking loop that does generic calculations (increment, check against zero etc), which is very concise (which is an excellent thing), but it looks very non-descriptive. There would be no way you can make it look good, but to put a short comment above it saying what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly - it is usually more expensive to maintain code over time than to write it in the first place. Maintenance costs are minimized if code is more readable.

There are three audiences for your code. You should think of how valuable their time is while you are formatting:

1. **Fellow coders**, including your co-workers and code-reviewers. You
   want these people to have a high reputation of you. You should write code that is easily understandable for them.
2. **Your future self**. Convoluted code may be obvious while you are
   writing it, but pick it up again in two weeks, and you will not
   remember what it means. The 'concise' statement that you wrote in 10
   minutes will someday take you 20 minutes to decipher.
3. **The Optimizing Compiler**, which will produce efficient code no matter
   whether your line is concise or not. The compiler does not care - try to save time for the other two. (Cue angry remarks about this item. I am in favor of writing efficient code, but concise styles like the one we are describing here will not affect compiler efficiency.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the compiler's skill at making good machine code. Its job is to turn human readable code into bits, and it's quite good at it, so keep the code "human readable."

Answer (score 1):

Bad practice, because not easy to parse. I'd do

```
while (*t) ++t;
```

and let the compiler do the tiny bit of optimization.

The textual translation of it reads even shorter than yours

> advance `t` until it points to a `0`

Answer (score 0):

Although you can write some pretty clever code in one line in C, it's usually not good practice in terms of readability and ease of maintenance.  What's straightforward for you to understand may look completely foreign to someone maintaining your code in future.

You need to strike a balance between conciseness and readability.  To this end, it's usually better to separate the code out so each line does one thing.